# Imported gradle projects not compiling within Eclipse

Tags: java, eclipse, gradle

We have a multi-project setup where a common module is shared among applications. Each module has it's own code and test cases and the libraries are picked up from an internal Maven repository. The dependencies are logically related as follows

- `Shared` depends on `Internal`
- `App A` depends on `Shared`
- `App B` depends on `Shared`

The physical structure is as follows

```
- App_a
  - src ( Code for `App a` & `Shared` module )
  - etc
  - test
    - unit 
      - src
  - build.gradle
  - settings.gradle
  - modules
    - Shared  
      - build.gradle 
      - settings.gradle
    - Internal
      - src
      - build.gradle

- App_b
 - build.gradle
 - settings.gradle
```

`Internal`, `Shared`, `App A`, `App B`, etc all have independent gradle scripts with the sub-projects defined in `settings.gradle` for each top level project ( `Shared`, `App A`, `App B`, etc). The Gradle scripts for this setup were recently created and everything works just fine from the command line.

I recently updated the Gradle scripts to work with Eclipse. Eclipse imports the projects correctly and is able to create projects for the sub projects as well. I am able to run all the gradle tasks from the `Gradle Tasks` view successfully (including ones from the eclipse plugin), but for some reason Eclipse is not using the dependent libraries and shows compilation errors. I am unable to run the applications or run JUnit tests via Eclipse because of this.

In Eclipse

- The project dependencies appear to be setup correctly i.e. Shared depends on `Internal`, `App A` depends on `Shared`, etc.
- The library tab for each project seems to be correct as well. It has a folder called `Gradle Dependencies` which when expanded shows the list of libraries configured in `build.gradle`.

I tried searching around but didn't find any solution. Any help on this would be appreciated.

My setup is as follows

- Java: 1.8
- Eclipse: Luna
- Gradle: 2.1
- Gradle IDE: 3.6.0.201405280533-M1

**Update on 17th Oct 2014:**

I have managed to make progress. I had to comment out a few things, but overall a big improvement.

The build script for each module set`s up the source & resources for Java and Test sourceSets. 
 When I was trying to import them in Eclipse, all projects were importing properly except `Shared`. Eclipse was reporting a source path error for `Shared` which I had missed. With `Shared` not compiling, `App a` & `App b` were not compiling either.

For some reason while importing 'Shared', Eclipse ends up importing the unit test source directory ( `test/unit/src`) twice and then complains about the duplicate entry. I tried to delete this project and re-import as a normal project (`Import > General > Existing Projects into Workspace`) and as a Gradle project (`Import > Gradle > Gradle Project`) but the error didn't go away.

I commented out the `test` sourceSet and it's compile dependencies and tried again. This time it worked. I am now able to compile all the projects via eclipse, I am also able to run & debug programs and execute test cases for all modules except `Shared`.

The `Shared` module is different from `Internal` in how it's laid out (both are sub-projects in Gradle), `Shared`'s source code & tests are not inside it's project directory, they reside with the source of `App a`, which is the parent directory of `Shared` (See directory structure above). This is legacy from the time the application was much smaller. This has been handled by using inclusion & exclusion filters to separate the source code & tests for `App a` & `Shared`. These gradle scripts work fine on the command line.

I have narrowed the problem to the following snippet from `Shared`'s build script. Everything works if the test sourceSet is commented out.

```
sourceSets {
    main {
        java {
            srcDirs = [ file('../../src/') ]

            include 'com/abc/app1/service/**'
            include 'com/abc/app1/util/**'

            ... 
        } 

        resources {
            ...
        } 
    }

//    test {
//        java {
//            srcDirs = [ 
//                file('../../test/unit/src'),
//                file('../../test/unit/etc/')
//            ]
//
//            exclude 'com/abc/app1/web/**'
//            include 'com/abc/app1/service/**'
//            include 'config/app-dao_test.xml'
//        } 
//
//        resources {
//            ...
//        } 
//    }
//}
```

Comment: You need to be more specific when describing your project setup. Ideally add a (reduced?) sample where the problem can be reproduced. Showing us yoru `build.gradle` file(s). You can check the output of `gradle dependencies` and content of `.classpath` files in your projects to see if they match.

Comment: Added more detail to the question. The dependencies as defined in the script and what show up in Eclipse do seem to match. I am probably missing something simple but can't figure out what it is!